# Finding recursive equation by algorithm

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory

I want some help in this algorithm

```
int two(int n)
{
   int sum = 0;
   int i;
   if n == 0
      return 7;
   for(i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
      sum += two(i);
   return sum;
}
```

I try to find the recursive equation but i don't know how.
Any idea??

Comment: If you are trying to work out what the code snippet does, ask yourself what would happen if it was called with n=0, what happens if it is called with n=1, what happens if it is called with n=2, n=3? Is there a pattern here?

Answer (score 2):

```
two(0) = 7

two(i) = two(0) + two(1) + ... + two(i-1) 

two(i) = Σ(Two(i)) with i = 0 to n-1
```

I hope this helps. This is the steps you should follow to get a recursive equation.

Example:`two(3)`

```
two(3) = two (2) + two(1) + two(0)

two(2) = two(1) + two(0)

two(1) = two(0)

two(0) = 7

two(1) = 7

two(2) = 7 + 7

two(3) = 7 + 7 + (7 + 7)  = 28
```

Comment: Namely the equation is T(n) = Σ(T(i))  with i = 0 to n-1  ??

Comment: Yes! I don't know how to add mathematical symbols! I have updated it with direct formula.

Comment: @WillNess I have added the example.

Answer (score 0):

your recursive equation is

```
two(n) = 7                         , n == 0
       = SUM( two(i) )[i=0..n-1]   , n > 0
```

writing out few terms in the sequence, starting from 0, we get

```
two(n)[n=0,1..] = 7, 7, 14, 28, 56, ...
```

your recurrence equation is then

```
two(n) = 7                , n <= 1
       = two(n-1) * 2     , n > 1
```

The closed form solution is then

```
two(n) = 7             , n == 0
       = 7 * 2^ ...    , n > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help all of you..I appreciate that..I get it.Thanks a lot.